# do we have to use encoding algorithm to represent chromosome in genetic algorithm or we can just encode on our own?

Tags: encoding, genetic-algorithm

if we have teachers as a gene and there are three teachers `{harry,sam,bran}`
then we use 2 bit binary value and assign value to teachers as:

```
harry=00 sam=01 bran=10
```

if we can do this what to do for that unused binary value 11?

Comment: You can have a "repairing function" which takes as input an infeasible solution and outputs a feasible one. E.g., this function could replace value 11 with 00, 01, or 10, chosen randomly.

Comment: so we need to check each chromosome in new population if the chromosome contains invalid combination? and if exist replace it with valid one??

Comment: If you want to work within a feasible solution space, yes. Otherwise you can choose to work with infeasible solutions by, for example, giving fitness penalties to infeasible chromosomes.

Comment: thank you Phillippe for your time and solution :)

Answer (score 0):

In practice you would do `gene % upperBound` *either when writing* to a genotype (to ensure all genotypes are always valid) *or when reading* a genotype (to map any "raw" genotype to valid values).

It might be beneficial to have a non-normalized "raw" genotypes in some types of [evolutionary algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm), e.g. in [grammatical evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_evolution).